# GetCacheDependency not called in custom VirtualPathProvider

Tags: c#, virtualpathprovider

I've written a custom implementation of [VirtualPathProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which allows me to pull images from Azure Blob Storage. The provider does its thing but calls `GetFile` upon every request which isn't great for performance.

**GetFile**

```
public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
{
    string path = this.FormatVirtualPath(virtualPath);
    if (!path.StartsWith(this.pathPrefix, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
    }

    string fileSystemPath = this.RemovePathPrefix(path);
    return new FileSystemVirtualFile(
                       virtualPath, 
                       () =>
                       this.fileSystem.Value.OpenFile(fileSystemPath));
}
```

Since I know the last modified date of the blob I thought it would be a good idea to add a bit of caching but I can't seem to get anything working.

Reading around it seems I need to override the methods `GetCacheDependency` and `GetFileHash` which I have done so as follows:

**GetCacheDependency**

```
public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath,
                                  IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, 
                                  DateTime utcStart)
{
    string path = this.FormatVirtualPath(virtualPath);

    if (!path.StartsWith(this.pathPrefix, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return base.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, 
                                       virtualPathDependencies, 
                                       utcStart);
    }

    return new BlobCacheDependency(
                                 this.fileSystem
                                     .Value.GetLastModified(path)
                                     .DateTime.ToUniversalTime());
}
```

**GetFileHash**

```
public override string GetFileHash(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies)
{
    string path = this.FormatVirtualPath(virtualPath);
    if (!path.StartsWith(this.pathPrefix, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return base.GetFileHash(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies);
    }

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(virtualPath.ToCharArray());

    using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);

        // Concatenate the hash bytes into one long String.
        return hash.Aggregate(
            new StringBuilder(32),
            (sb, b) => sb.Append(b.ToString("X2",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
            .ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
    }
}
```

I also have a custom `CacheDependency` implementation.

```
public class BlobCacheDependency : CacheDependency
{
    public BlobCacheDependency(DateTime lastModifiedUtc)
    {
        this.SetUtcLastModified(lastModifiedUtc);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately neither the of those other methods ever get called when requesting the images. I'm not sure what is missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so an answer to this is to set the response cache within the `Open()` method in my `VirtualFile` implementation. This allows the browser to cache the file.

It's a little hacky but works. In my code it looks like this now.

```
public override Stream Open()
{
    // Set the response headers here. It's a bit hacky.
    HttpCachePolicy cache = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache;
    cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;

    IFileSystem azureBlobFileSystem = FileSystemProviderManager.Current.GetUnderlyingFileSystemProvider("media");
    int maxDays = ((AzureBlobFileSystem)azureBlobFileSystem).FileSystem.MaxDays;

    cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddDays(maxDays));
    cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(maxDays, 0, 0, 0));
    cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);

    return this.stream();
}
```

See

http://forums.asp.net/t/1745003.aspx?VirtualPathProvider+files+do+not+have+cache+control+headers